# Failed to call function "LoadSceneThing" of class ChangeSceneAfterThreeSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make it so that it will change to the next scene after 3 seconds, but I will only get an error9 ([Error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psQh8.jpg)). I added a code sample.

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;



public class ChangeSceneAfterThreeSeconds : MonoBehaviour

{


  public void Start() 
  {
     StartCoroutine("LoadSceneThing");
  
}


  public IEnumerator LoadSceneThing(string sceneToChange)
  
{
    
yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    
SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToChange);
  
}

}
```

Comment: `LoadSceneThing(string sceneToChange)` expects a string parameter. You are not passing a parameter. The [documentation for StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) has a few examples that show passing a parameter.

Comment: This question is not about using the Visual Studio application, so I've removed that tag for you.

Comment: How do you a a string parameter? Sorry, I am a beginner:)

Comment: From reading the docs (I don't do Unity), it seems like you might want `StartCoroutine(LoadSceneThing("hello"));`, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

just replace `StartCoroutine("LoadSceneThing");` by `StartCoroutine(LoadSceneThing("scene name"));`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! It really helped! Appreciate it.